# How to replace NDEBUG by C++ means

Tags: c++, preprocessor

So I use preprocessor macro `NDEBUG` to enable some checks for my debug build. But I would like to replace it with C++ constant to use it in `noexept` clause and in `static if`. I know I can probably achieve it like so:

```
// in constants.hpp

#ifdef NDEBUG
constexpr bool ndebug = true;
#else
constexpr bool ndebug = false;
#endif
```

But with `NDEBUG` you can, for example, supply `-D NDEBUG` flag to compiler, but for certain files you can manually specify `#undef NDEBUG`. So parts of code will be compiled with `NDEBUG` and parts will be compiled without it. So even within one translation unit there will be parts with defined `NDEBUG` and parts without it.

Is it possible with C++ means to devise something that will 100% conform to this behavior, so in every header file there would be compile-time `bool` constant with value based on `NDEBUG`?

You can of course create constants with different name in each file, if it is the only way can you at least somehow automate this?

Comment: There's no standard C++ way to force macros or variables one way or another. But there are compiler extensions which can force-include a header file into the beginning of the current translation-unit. for example the GCC `-include` command-line option.

Comment: `but for certain files you can manually specify #undef NDEBUG` So don't do it. I do not think I have ever seen `#undef NDEBUG` in any sane code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use variable or function, you will probably have ODR violation if you mix file with NDEBUG defined or not with those variable/function.

You can though declare a MACRO with a value matching NDEBUG presence.

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
# define NDEBUG_VALUE true
#else
# define NDEBUG_VALUE false
#endif
```

> to use it in noexept clause and in static if

But still care, as ODR-violation can happen quickly.

All definitions should be identical.